# Most appropriate way to load data from internet into listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple query but have been picking my mind around a lot lately without a straight solution.
I have a listview with loads quote data from internet. The list item is a bit complex but that is not a problem . The listview is loaded using a loader which fetches the quote data from internet, parses the json and populates the VOs. The list of VOs is set in the adapter and the `notifyDataSetChanged` changed is called which reloads the list through the adapter's `getView`

now the pattern i have used here is:

- user clicks a button, we open a fragment
- the fragment has `LoaderCallbacks` and we initiate the loader in `onActivityCreated`
- the loader has a cached Thread Pool executor (I cant use async loaders as they essentially use linear loading not parallel across the Android API versions) which creates a download worker for each stock.
- the worker hits the url and downloads the data, parses the JSON using GSON, creates an object and puts it in the loader's arraylist.
- Loader uses a latch to wait till all the quotes are downloaded.
- once all are done the list is loaded.

My problem is that when the listview has a lots of stocks, like 70 to 90 the quote downloading process becomes slow. ON a direct wifi network it takes about 1.5 to 2 seconds for the list to load. On mobile data networks like 2G and 3G and Hybrids it takes about 30-40 seconds to load. Profiling shows majority time spend in reading data from stream. Each quote URL hit is about 700-800 bytes and takes about 800-900ms to load. I am using `HttpURLConnection` to load the URLs.

I cannot use the dynamic loading pattern in list as i have menu items to filter and sort the listview. They wont make any sense if we don't have all the quote data in the list in the first place.

is there any better way to do this? I have read the things around and have tried "new async task for each row in the list when that row becomes visible on screen" but cant use it as such as that would mean lazy loading of data.

**Edit to show how the Data is deserialized:**

```
InputStream inputstreamObj = (InputStream) conn.getContent();//getInputStream();
        if(inputstreamObj != null){
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputstreamObj);
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new CompanyCorpAnnouncementsVODeserializer());
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            retVal = gson.fromJson(reader, List.class);
        }
```

Comment: another thing i though was to keep the downloaded JSONs in SQLITE DB and load them when the fragment loads. Then when the loader downloads fresh data again put that data in Db and update the listview. But thats just a lame workaround to the problem that doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: Am i reading this right, you're downloading 70-90 quotes x 800kbs per stock quote?

Comment: Sorry a mistake. Its about 700-800 bytes ...not kbs Updated the question with this issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to offload the requests to a server, then download the full item when it's complete? That would probably help with a lot of the overhead, per device.

Comment: @MichaelTodd: I tried that already. By clubbing about 2 to 3 stocks together in one 'get quote hit' i could decrease the number of hits (or saw threads) but the payload size is roughly still the same except a few bytes for the headers which are not sent again. This approach actually helps the wifi connection type better, instead of mobile net. When in mobile net connection it takes a far longer to read the response back from the stream.

Comment: Actually i have another hunch. I use GSON to deserialize the JSON and in doing so i pass it the reader stream from my connection. See the edit in question about the code. Would it be better to first read the whole data into a String and pass that String to GSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I am answering it myself.

There is no plausible way to achieve this. App design methodology needs to restrict the list size to a comfortable level. In my case i am shifting focus from 1 watch list of 100-150 stocks to multiple watch lists of 30 stocks each. Since i cant drop the filtering and sorting functionality so this is the only plausible way.

Additionally  need to track network state changes and adjust the executor to single threaded from caching one. Go full throttle when wi-fi is on and display dialog or toast messages when mobile net is on.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are reading this and have similar issues, use paginated 'load more stuff on scroll end' design instead of breaking your list into pieces.
I ended using a full throttled load backed by a cached threadpool executor when on Wifi or 3G/4G and falling back to a fixed thread pool executor of 2 threads and loading 6 at a time when on any other network. Works great for me.